# SKSpriteNodeがnilになってしまう

Tags: swift, xcode

XcodeのPlaygroundで、スプライトを動かす簡単なゲームを作っています

スプライトの表示で、このようなコードを作りました

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let sceneWidth = 768.0
let sceneHeight = 1024.0
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: sceneWidth, 
height: sceneHeight))
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
let character = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "SobacchiStand.png")
```

しかし、characterがnilになってしまっています

画像自体はPlaygroundに元からある「Resources」フォルダに入れた「SobacchiStand.png」です

どのようにすれば画像を表示できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let character = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "SobacchiStand.png")
```

この行を、こう書き換えてみてください。

```
let character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SobacchiStand.png")
```

[SpriteKit - SKNode - init(file​Named:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483083-init)

ここから引用：

> Parameters
>   **filename**
>   The name of the file, without a file extension. The file must be in the app’s main bundle and have a .sks filename extension.

拡張子`.sks`のSpriteKit Sceneファイルを読み込んで、`SKScene`インスタンスを生成するときに使うイニシアライザです。`SKSpriteNode`のイメージを読み込むのは、`init(imageNamed:​)`を使います。

Comment: ありがとうございます
そのように変えてみたのですが、SpriteKit Image dataとなります
プレビューができないのですが、正しい挙動なのでしょうか

Comment: 正しい挙動です。そして、ご提示のコードは完全なコードではありませんよね。そのコードだけでは、「プレビューができ」るようにはなりません。それは理解なさっていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます
その後addChildで無事表示ができました

ありがとうございました